# How to read key from unknown typed object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

The following snippet won't compile with `typescript@4.0.2`.

```js
const foo: unknown = {bar: 'baz'}

if (foo && typeof foo === 'object' && 'bar' in foo) {
  console.log(foo.bar)
}
```

The tsc error being

```
Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

How does one convince `tsc` that foo can have arbitrarily named keys without an explicit cast?

Here's a playground link. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGBXMBrMIDuYYC8MA3gEYCGATigOQUBeNAvgFAsCWcMAFAiDADIBMKAE8ADgFMQXPoQJEaIUgCtJwKDUHC6VLe3x8AlCRYwYoSCAA2kgHTWQAc16I7FSkZZMgA

Answer (score 7):

Type `unknown` is type safe and hence one way to get around this problem would be to be cast the object `foo` as `any` or an interface having `bar` as a property.

```
const foo: unknown = {bar: 'baz'};

console.log((foo as any).bar);
```

OR,

```
const foo: unknown = {bar: 'baz'};

interface HasBar {
   bar: string;
}

console.log((foo as HasBar).bar);
```

Comment: Its not possible without an explicit cast. You need to use typescript ignores if you want that anyway! If there was a way to bypass this without casts, then no one would trust typescript and typescript wouldn't have existed in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [user defined typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). You can check if an element belongs to a type by using it:

```
type Bar = {bar: string};

function isBar(element: unknown): element is Bar  {
  return (element as Bar).bar !== undefined;
}

const foo: unknown = {bar: 'baz'}
if (isBar(foo)) {
  console.log(foo.bar)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbwEaIFxQM7AICWAdgOYC%20A3ALABQ9AZgK4kDGwRA9iVEXvAQAKCABsIAWwglguVgGsSXAO4kAlLjGTpwPnliIo6ekYQRgzBLxHipMqHH2C1AOixIAhMlSsAJhEZSCF9aOgp6ejYeAihGLi45EkUVXlRMHCgAciwAL0zwuiJGKCF%20QSE4rjU1YzojKJI8LnEXUS4yCvi3RDV6CiA)

Comment: I would recommend that your `isBar` check that the `bar` property is actually a `string` and not just defined.  Otherwise you run into trouble with things like `const badBar: unknown = {bar: 123}`.  My suggestion looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1a2w).

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the tip.